# Updating and retrieving data with async/await issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have an async method that calls an api to write the data and retrieve it. However the get method always returns the previous result. I get the updated data if I introduce a delay between the method calls.

```
public async Task<ServerResult<IEnumerable<int>>> UpdateData(int data)
{
    var updatedResult = await apiClient.UpdateAsync(data);
    //If the updatedResult.StatusCode != 200 return appropriate message, otherwise get the updated data and return it. 
    var getResult = await apiClient.GetAllAsync();
    return getResult
}
```

My understanding of the async/await is that each awaited method is asynchronously sequentially executed which means the `GetAllAsync` runs only after `UpdateAsync` completes (i.e. `Task.Run(() => UpdateAsync(data)).ContinueWith(t => return GetAllAsync())`). How can I make sure GetAllAsync runs only after UpdateAsync without resorting to delays or have the client make a separate get call?

Comment: The problem is not in the provided code. Check that `UpdateAsync` returns task which will complete only after data update, check that your api behaves correctly and check that there is no caching somewhere (in the `apiClient` or the server app behind it).

Answer (score 2):

What happens inside the api client? It seems to me that the code inside it, does not await on the call. You need to await all the included asynchronous operations.

The line:

```
var updatedResult = await apiClient.UpdateAsync(data);
```

Will return the execution to the original code execution path only when it's completely done.

If inside the `UpdateAsync` code there is a line without the await keyword, then it would be fire and forget.

Maybe this happens on the server side. Maybe the server side queues the request and does not save on the spot. Check all these and update the question if there is still an issue.